# `img` element with `lang` attribute: language of the image itself?

Tags: image, html, lang

(I'm interested in HTML 4.01 *and* HTML5, if there should be differences)

Does the `lang` attribute on an `img` element apply to the `src` attribute, too? Or is it only for the `alt` and `title` attributes?

Example:

```
<img src="example.png" alt="a red foobar" lang="en" />
```

Is the image "example.png" considered to be in English? (think of screenshots of a forum thread, or a graphical representation of a word, or a scan of a document)

If it's true, images with non-linguistic content would need to get `lang="zxx"`. But that would apply to the `alt`/`title` attributes, too, which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTML 4.01 defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#adef-lang) the `lang` attribute as specifying “the base language of an element's attribute values and text content”, whereas [HTML5 defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#attr-lang) it as “the primary language for the element's contents and for any of the element's attributes that contain text”. The difference is apparently in the formulation only. The `lang` attribute specifies the language of `alt` and `title` attribute as well as other attributes that may contain prose text, as opposite to code-like values like URLs or `style` attributes, where (human) language is not applicable.

The `src` attribute itself is not of any (human) language, logically. So the question is whether the `lang` attribute extends to the image denoted by the `src` attribute. This is a fairly theoretical question – what impact on software behavior could the answer possibly have? Anyway, the answer depends on what we understand as “text content” (images are text in a sense, in formatting, but probably HTML 4.01 means to refer to actual character data only) and as “element’s contents” (is an image part of the `img` element’s contents?). Overall, it seems that the language of the image (though a feasible concept) cannot be specified in HTML.

So there is no need to worry about images with non-linguistic content. For text content that is “non-linguistic” (i.e. not text in any human language but e.g. some code notation, or a random sequence of character), using `lang=""` is what HTML5 recommends. It’s also the practical approach. In the few cases whete `lang` attribute has any impact, as in automatic hyphenation, `lang=""` effectively means that no language rules are applied (e.g., no hyphenation). This is different from omitting the attribute, which means that the element inherits language information from its parent.

Comment: Never knew `lang` accepted an empty string, but it makes sense to do so. Was `lang=""` ever valid before HTML5?

Comment: @BoltClock, `lang=""` is not valid in HTML 4.01 (even in the formal sense), as it declares the attribute with `NAME` value. But HTML 4.01 is rather outdated in this respect. XHTML5 cites BCP 47, which explicitly defines the empty string as a possible language code.

Comment: Regarding `lang` values: The value `zxx` means "no linguistic content", while the empty value could also mean "unknown" (similar to `und` for "undetermined"), or am I wrong?

Comment: @unor, right. But note that the empty value is suitable e.g. for a text input field where the user may enter text in any language.

Comment: But the image can contain a text, for example signboard. Not to mention book/documnet scans. I can imagine filtering images dependent on the language of the user in search engine.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 4.01, [section 13.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.8) says:

> The language of the alternate text is specified by the `lang` attribute.

In HTML5, [it says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.lang):

> Specifies the primary language for the contents of the element and for any of the element’s attributes that contain text.

I can't find anything in the current HTML5 draft that defines the relationship between the `alt` and `lang` attributes as explicitly as the HTML 4.01 spec does. Hopefully it'll be clarified later, but I would assume for now that there isn't any change, and that what it *does* state is just as applicable.

Neither spec states an explicit relationship between the `src` and `lang` attributes, but I wouldn't assume that the language of the source image itself corresponds to the `lang` attribute, since not all images will have linguistic content (as you've mentioned).

The same goes for `title` and `lang`, but this may depend on the element type, I'm not entirely sure. Again, what it *does* state in general above should be applicable to `title`.